# How is get_updates() of optimizers.SGD used in Keras during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am not familiar with the inner workings of Keras and have difficulty understanding how Keras uses the `get_updates()` function of optimizers.SGD during training.

I searched quite a while on the internet, but only got few details.  Specifically, my understanding is that the parameters/weights update rule of SGD is defined in the `get_updates()` function.  But it appears that `get_updates()` isn't *literally* called in every iteration during training; otherwise 'moments' wouldn't carry from one iteration to the next to implement momentum correctly, as it's reset in every call, c.f. optimizers.py:

```python
shapes = [K.get_variable_shape(p) for p in params]
moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
    v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
    self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))
```

As pointed out in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7502, get_updates() only defines 'a symbolic computation graph'.  I'm not sure what that means.  Can someone give a more detailed explanation of how it works?

For example, how is the 'v' computed in one iteration got passed to 'moments' in the next iteration to implement momentum? I'd also appreciate it if someone can point me to some tutorial about how this works.

Thanks a lot!  (BTW, I'm using tensorflow, if it matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_updates() defines graph operations that update the gradients.
When the graph is evaluated for training it will look somehow like this:

- forward passes compute a prediction value
- loss computes a cost
- backward passes compute gradients
- gradients are updated

Updating the gradients is a graph computation itself; i.e. the snippet of code that you quote defines how to perform the operation by specifying which tensors are involves and what math operations occur. The math operations themselves are not occurring at that point.

moments is a vectors of tensors defined in the code above. The code creates a graph operation that updates each moments element.

Every iteration of the graph will run this update operation.

The following link tries to explain the concept of the computational graph in TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs

Keras uses the same underlying ideas but abstract the user from having to deal with the low level details. Defining a model in traditional TensorFlow 1.0 API requires a much higher level of detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  But I'm still a bit confused.  I suppose the last 2 lines of code above define how 'moments' is updated and they are executed in every iteration of the graph.  What about the first 2 lines of the code snippet?  I suppose they're not executed in every iteration.  So, more generally, how do I tell which lines of the get_updates() function are executed in every iteration?  Is there a rule in general?

Comment: The snippet you quote is executed when the graph is created. When model.fit() is called the graph is executed. Suggestion: use TensorBoard callback to generate a representation of the graph. The computational graph consists of a set of operations on tensors.The line above ```self.updates.append(...)``` is adding a set of operations that will be executed at each epoch by the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification/suggestion.  I really appreciate it!